# Images won't appear in wordpress.org site

Tags: wordpress, image

Here is the site that I am working on.

http://afinderskeeper.com/

Here is an example of the logo image that I want at the top
http://afinderskeeper.com/?attachment_id=64

The theme is mayashop, and I am having issues with the images loading. In the media library I am able to see all the images. In the theme options menu in the backend, it asks me to enter the url of the logo image/ favicon/ etc. into the text field. So for the logo, I am simply pasting that second url from above, save, but I still get the placeholder box, not even the correct size.

I was having a redirect issue earlier and couldn't even view any of the images.
It just kept taking a while to load and coming up with a redirect loop. I found online someone had switched the permalink, so I switched mine from "month and name" to "default" and now I can at least see the images on the second link, but I still cannot figure out why they don't show up in the proper places. I hope this makes sense.

I will also mention that I don't really know any php so if this is what it takes, please be very specific for me, thanks!

Comment: Isn't the media library more for media that is considered content for the posts? If the image is part of the design, you want to be storing it inside the theme itself.

Comment: Patrick is correct. Nicolas, as a beginner, his message may not have been explicit enough. The mistake is that you're using the url that is publicly available. Very literally, you are trying to load everything you see on the screen here http://afinderskeeper.com/?attachment_id=64 into that header area (the menus, the css, everything). It's doing you a favor and crapping out. Instead, use the file url. That'll take care of it.

Comment: @evanv Good call - thanks for elaborating on that for me.

Comment: No probs Bob, er, Patrick :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong urls for the header image and, possibly, the other images that are giving you trouble as well. Instead of referencing http://afinderskeeper.com/?attachment_id=64, you want to edit that image from the media library and get the **file url**. It will be something like http://afinderskeeper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/afk_header_logo.jpg

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked. Did this address whatever issues you were having with images loading as well, or was that the same issue?

Comment: Yes it did @evanv that is really making everything a lot easier now!

Answer (score 1):

I am just a random stranger on the internet, but I have to thank you guys! Your solution fixed a problem on my site that has bugged me for ages!